# how to fill Date Array With The Dates in android

Tags: android, parsing, date

I have  the Dates 01/01/2012 ,01/05/2012, 01/06/2012 and many more
 i want to fill these dates in 
These Dates are coming from server i need to parse these date and fill the `Date Array`
`List <Date[]>`

i can give u static data  it should be filled like this

```
dates.add(new Date[12]);
dates.get(i)[0] = new Date(108, 9,1);
dates.get(i)[1] = new Date(108, 9, 8);
dates.get(i)[2] = new Date(108, 9, 15);
dates.get(i)[3] = new Date(108, 9, 22);
dates.get(i)[4] = new Date(108, 9, 29);
```

how Can i do That 
What i have done is

```
arrXaxis= new ArrayList<Date[]>();// Defining Array
```

At the Time of Parsing

```
Integer intCount=p2.getPropertyCount(); /// from Server
```

They are coming in a form of String

```
arrXaxis.add(new Date[intCount]);
arrXaxis.add(new Date(o.getProperty("Month").toString()));
```

It is giving me Error

Your help would be greatful Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you sure you want an ArrayList of Date[]? This gives you an array of arrays, not an array of dates.

Comment: @kyogs I am not getting any Data in my array Class Cast ExCeption

Comment: @Ridcully yeaa i want this only so how can i do that ?
gimme any idea i have given u the dates

Comment: Can you please add to your question, what you get from the server exactly? As I understand it, you get a text with one date of the form 01/01/2012 per line and you want to convert those dates to Date objects and put those Date objects into an ArrayList. Is this correct?

Comment: @Ridcully Yea you are absolutely right :) but i have managed to do it on my own  thanks for your help and concern thnk u